# Getting 500 response in Go code while in postman and Python script it is working correctly

Tags: python-3.x, go, http-status-code-500

When i hit the endpoint via through Postman i get 200 response and same with Python script it is working fine but when i try to hit endpoint via Go code it gives 500 response.

This is my Go code, when i run this, it is giving me 500 internal server error. I am getting this error, `response &{500 Internal Server Error 500 HTTP/2.0 2 0 map\[Content-Type:\[text/html\] Date:\[Wed, 16 Nov 2022 04:48:50 GMT\] Server:\[Microsoft-IIS/10.0\] Via:\[1.1 f83562bde87e361cdd8300e36b25925e.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)\] X-Amz-Cf-Id:\[-N4TrERntpfdaH-JVzyKbCvP7_NAwPbVWwGi6ADkcyLn45DZDXJ0gg==\] X-Amz-Cf-Pop:\[DEL51-P4\] X-Cache:\[Error from cloudfront\] X-Content-Type-Options:\[nosniff\] X-Frame-Options:\[SAMEORIGIN\] X-Xss-Protection:\[1; mode=block\]\] {0xc00042adc0} -1 \[\] false false map\[\] 0xc000194000 0xc0001a62c0}`

The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.

```
package main

import (
"bytes"
"fmt"
"io"
"io/ioutil"
"log"
"mime/multipart"
"net/http"
"os"
"path"
)

func main() {
// make request body
filePath := "/Users/ashishkumarsaw/Downloads/AdharCard.pdf"

    file, err := os.Open(filePath)
    fmt.Println("file", file)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    defer file.Close()
    
    var requestBody bytes.Buffer
    
    multiPartWriter := multipart.NewWriter(&requestBody)
    fileName := path.Base(filePath)
    fmt.Println("fileName", fileName)
    fileWriter, err := multiPartWriter.CreateFormFile("", fileName)
    fmt.Println("fileWriter", fileWriter)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    
    _, err = io.Copy(fileWriter, file)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    
    multiPartWriter.Close()
    
    // make request
    
    url := "https://d2jpi7ffs6imr7.cloudfront.net/WealthSideAPI/api/services/app/MFPdfProcessing/ProcessMFPdf?filename=SampleCams.pdf&password=Glenn123&type=cams&clientcode=RISEA98766"
    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", url, &requestBody)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", multiPartWriter.FormDataContentType())
    
    // perform the request and process the response
    
    client := &http.Client{}
    response, err := client.Do(req)
    fmt.Println("response", response)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    
    fmt.Println(string(body))

}
```

This is my Pyhton code. When i run this script this give me 200 success response. The response i get,

`"{"result":null,"targetUrl":null,"success":true,"error":null,"unAuthorizedRequest":false,"\__abp":true}"`

```
import requests

url = "https://d2jpi7ffs6imr7.cloudfront.net/WealthSideAPI/api/services/app/MFPdfProcessing/ProcessMFPdf?filename=SampleCams.pdf&password=Glenn123&type=cams&clientcode=RISEA98766"

payload={}
files=\[
('file',('AdharCard.pdf',open('/Users/ashishkumarsaw/Downloads/AdharCard.pdf','rb'),'application/pdf'))
\]
headers = {}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload, files=files)

print(response.text)
```

I need to get go code Work so that it won't give 500 response code and works fine as python script do.

Comment: can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Can you check the sent content-type from go code? According to the error it is text\html. Or try to call from postman to check the content-type can cause this kind of error

Comment: map[Content-Type:[multipart/form-data; boundary=50a846fb1b0e35a757d23c5f19a7d11ab4234c6483fad053978496aedb58]]